# Update foreign key references

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys

I have 2 tables in which one column in one table will reference one in another table.
I would like to know how can I make `table B (referenced)`'s column data changed whenever `table A(referencing)`'s column data is changed

That is

```
A [a1, a2]
a1 = {1,2}

B [b1, b2]
```

`b1` is referenced by `a1`, and `b1 = {1,2}` therefore if I change a1 values using phpmyadmin to `{2,5}` then click save, after that I would like b1's values are automagically  changed too.

**Update:**

Now it works, but I don't see any referenced data in the second table? I mean the values of `b1` is empty, It should be the same with `a1` I think.

Comment: For update: please provide more details. What operation did you do and what the expected result? You aren't so clear ...

Comment: Did you *add* any data to the second table? Foreign keys don't *add* data for you.  They just make sure that, if *you* add data, that data already exists in another table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, create the foreign keys with [`ON UPDATE CASCADE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) (requires InnoDB for the storage engine, but that's a good default).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ON UPDATE CASCADE` clause

[Take a look](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)